# React Native - Component update parent

Tags: react-native, components

I'm making an app in react native and I'm facing a little problem.
I finished the first layout and now I want to change the style all over the app with a second layout
This is what I have in my parent.
As you can see I use AsyncStorage to check when you open again the app the last selected layout. It all working perfectly.

```
export default class Home extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            view:0
        }
    }
    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.checkStructureView();
    }
    checkStructureView = async() =>
    {
        const StructureView = await 
        AsyncStorage.getItem('@StructureView');
        if(StructureView == 1)
        {
            this.setState({
                view:1
            })
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({
                view:0
            })
        }
    }
    render() 
    {
        if(this.state.view == 1)
        {
            return(
             <ChangeView/>
             ...
             )
        }
        else
        {
          return(
             <ChangeView/>
             ...
             )
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my component ChangeView. It's a little bit messy because I have for each button active/inactive styles. This is also working perfectly, but the problem is that when I click on the button to change the layout will not change it, only after I refresh the app.
First I added this inside the parent and after I updated the state, the layout has changed instantly but I have more pages where I need to add this component, that's why I'm using an component.
So my question is how can I update instantly the parent state so my layout changes every time I click on the component button without reloading the app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native'

export default class ChangeView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            position: this.props.position,
            view:0,
            view1:require(`../assets/icons/view1_inactive.png`),
            view2:require(`../assets/icons/view2_active.png`)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.checkViewStructure();
    }
    checkViewStructure = async()=>
    {
        const StructureView = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@StructureView');
        if(StructureView == '0')
        {
            this.setState({
                view1:require(`../assets/icons/view1_inactive.png`),
                view2:require(`../assets/icons/view2_active.png`)
            })
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({
                view1:require(`../assets/icons/view1_active.png`),
                view2:require(`../assets/icons/view2_inactive.png`)
            })         
        }
    }
    changeToList = async() =>
    {
        const StructureView = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@StructureView');
        if(StructureView == '0')
        {
            await AsyncStorage
            .setItem('@StructureView', '1')
            .then( () => {
                //
            })
            .catch( () => {
                alert('Something happened! Please try again later.');
            });
            this.setState({
                view1:require(`../assets/icons/view1_active.png`),
                view2:require(`../assets/icons/view2_inactive.png`)
            })
        }
    }
    changeToPics = async() =>
    {
        const StructureView = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@StructureView');
        if(StructureView == '1')
        {
            await AsyncStorage
            .setItem('@StructureView', '0')
            .then( () => {
                //
            })
            .catch( () => {
                alert('Something happened! Please try again later.');
            });     
            this.setState({
                view1:require(`../assets/icons/view1_inactive.png`),
                view2:require(`../assets/icons/view2_active.png`)
            })
        }
    }
    render()
    {

        if(this.state.position === 0) 
        return(
            <View style={{alignItems:'flex-end',marginTop:20,marginBottom:10,justifyContent:'flex-end',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress= {() => this.changeToList()}
                    >
                    <Image
                    source={this.state.view1}
                    style={{width:15,height:21,margin:5}}
                    />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress= {() => this.changeToPics()}
                    >
                    <Image
                    source={this.state.view2}
                    style={{width:15,height:21,margin:5}}
                    />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
        else
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ChangeView` component only changes state in that specific component. There are several ways of propagating change to the parent component. One way is to implement an `onChange` prop for the `ChangeView` component. Your `Home` component render function would then look like something like this:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.view == 1) {
    return(
      <ChangeView onChange={ (view) => this.setState({ view }) } />
      ...
    )
  } else {
    return(
      <ChangeView onChange={ (view) => this.setState({ view }) } />
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

You can read more about props here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

There are other ways of doing this if you have state handler for your application such as Redux.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Still doesn't work. Nothing happened on parent only after I refresh the app. Inside my component the state is changed but on my parent no.

Comment: @paulv Did you call this.props.onChange(view) in the ChangeView component? You need to call it for it to work. Please share your updated code so I can review it and help you.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I'm at the beginning and I've missed the component props. Now it's working perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @paulv that happens, I suggest you read the documentation on props and propTypes. You will be using it a lot.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question if you can drive me through. On Home tab I change the style and it changes perfectly. When I go to categories it's also changed because I have componentWillMount and there I call the AsyncStorage to check what style it is. But why on my Home tab the style doesn't change if I change it from Categories tab? Even if on my Home tab I also have componentWillMount? Can I update all the stacks instantly when component is called? Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you use a state manager to handle state changes in your application. I usually use Redux (https://redux.js.org/). That would make your life easier and you wouldn't have to be passing props between components all the time.